# Don't know how to resolve this unexpected EOF error

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash and am wondering what the problem is with this? Says the error is on line 44 and line 47. A copy of the error:

```
unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

This is my script so far:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/bash

#Basic setup for fedora. Updates and upgrades, then adds rpm fusion repos
dnf update
dnf upgrade
dnf install https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm
dnf update
dnf upgrade

#Now, for some basic software.
if ! command -v google-chrome &> /dev/null
then
    echo "Google chrome is not installed! Proceeding to install...
    dnf install google-chrome-stable
else
    echo "Google chrome is already installed. Skipping..."
fi
if ! command -v emacs &> /dev/null
then
    echo "Emacs is not installed! Proceeding to install..."
    dnf install emacs
else
    echo "Emacs is already installed. Skipping..."
fi
if ! command -v vim &> /dev/null
then
    echo "Vim is not installed! Proceeding to install..."
    dnf install vim
else
    echo "Vim is already installed. Skipping..."
fi
if ! command -v qbittorrent /dev/null
then
    echo "Qbittorrent is not installed! Proceeding to install..."
    dnf install qbittorrent
else
    echo "Qbittorrent is already installed. Skipping..."
fi
if ! command -v steam &> /dev/null
then
    echo "Steam is not installed! Proceeding to install..."
    dnf install steam
else
    echo "Steam is already installed. Skipping..."
exit
fi
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- you are obviously missing a closing quote. Don't post links, post the text of your script with `\`\`\`bash` on the line above and `\`\`\`` on the line below to format in fixed text with syntax highlight.

Comment: Where is the closing quote after `echo "Google ...` ? You can post to [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and it will point out the problem for you.

Comment: At line 13, the terminating double quote is missing.

Answer (score 2):

In line 13, your echo need (") at the end of the line:

```
echo "Google chrome is not installed! Proceeding to install... <-
```

It should be as:

```
echo "Google chrome is not installed! Proceeding to install..." <-
```

Answer (score 1):

@Milad alredy found the missing quote.
When writing code, consider avoiding duplicate code. In this case consider

```
install_when_needed () {
  checkname="${1%-stable}"
  displayname="$(sed -r 's/./\U&/;s/-/ /g' <<< ${checkname})"
  if ! command -v "${checkname}" &> /dev/null
  then
    echo "${displayname} is not installed! Proceeding to install..."
    dnf install "$1"
  else
    echo "${displayname} is already installed. Skipping..."
  fi
}

for prog in google-chrome-stable emacs vim qbittorrent steam; do
  install_when_needed "${prog}"
done
```